# How to transfer data to Slide Menu in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, label

How can I pass the String value to the SideMenuVC class from the RegisterViewController class?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear how RegisterViewController is linked to SideMenuVC in your question.

Anyway one possible solution is using a Singleton.

Here's an example:

**Singleton**

```
struct DummySingleton {
    static var shared = DummySingleton()
    var string = String()
}
```

**Set Singleton**

```
//In your RegisterViewController you set the singleton
DummySingleton.shared.string = "I am a string"
```

**In viewDidLoad in your SideMenuVC...**

```
label.text = DummySingleton.shared.string
```

**Conclusion**

It is not the better solution, using Singleton is not always a good solution in terms of memory handling, but it is the only thing I can suggest you so far with the information you provided in your question.

Comment: Many thanks, this option helped me, but in the future I will listen to your words and find the best way to implement this method;).